# How can I target specific html tags with Less

Tags: less, themes, adobe-brackets

I am trying to create a new theme for Brackets.

Brackets is using Less to colorize the code and so far I have entered this code to my theme.less file:

```
.cm-m-xml {color: #000;} // Making the text between the tags black.
.cm-tag  {color: #009;} // Making the letters between the < and > blue.
.cm-bracket {color: #009;} // Making the < and > blue.
.cm-attribute {color: #009;} // Making the attribute-text including the = blue.
.cm-string {color: #00f;} // Making the attribute-value including the "" blue.
```

ALL tags are colored blue with the .cm-tag and .cm-bracket rules.

The HTML looks like this (I cannot change how the HTML is):

```
<span class="cm-m-xml cm-tag cm-bracket">&lt;</span>
<span class="cm-m-xml cm-tag">h1</span>
<span class="cm-m-xml cm-tag cm-bracket">&gt;</span>
```

My question is: Can I use Less to color for instance the img elements in another color than the rest?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here with Less. If you want `img` elements alone to be in a separate color, you could add a separate class to them and style as appropriate. You don't even need Less for that. Coming to this specific case, all being blue in color is normal as per your CSS.

Comment: But i cannot change the HTML. I cannot add a new class. The HTML is as it is and I can only change the .less file that Brackets use for its color themes.

Comment: The reason I am looking into less is because it seems to have some sort of if/else capability. SInce i cannot change the HTML I am thinking maybe I can say IF the contents of the span element with cm-tag is img THEN use this color ELSE use this color.

Comment: While Less has guards to sort of mimick the if/else behavior, it certainly cannot read the contents of a tag and then decide styles based on it.

Comment: Ok. So i guess less is not what I am looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

Less compiles into (static) valid CSS code. So things you can not solve with CSS, can also not solve by Less.

Based on your question i expect that the HTML for the image will look like that shown below:

```
<span class="cm-m-xml cm-tag">img</span>
```

In the above `img` is the content of the `span` tag. You can not use CSS selectors based on their content, see: [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Your question can easily be solved with jQuery:

```
$(span:contains('img')).css('color','red');
```

The latest specification of CSS3 does not contain a content selector any more: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors